# How to change name of application in push notification?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification

I am using firebase in my application to send push notifications. When I created the firebase project, application's name was different. 
Later I need to change the name, but when the application receives notification, it still displays the old name.

Could anybody please help me to change the name of application displayed in notification?

Certificates were created with the old name of the application. Could that be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Try updating the Product Name in build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace the display name in xcode. Again create the new APNS certificate in the developer account. Then upload the new p12 or pem certificate in firebase console -> cloud message

Answer (score 0):

Your Push notifications are dependent on your Bundle Id and I don't think your app name has to do anything with it.

Make sure you are updating your app name at right places. Make sure `CFBundleDisplayName` is updated.

In some cases `CFBundleDisplayName` is based on other values, like `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`. So make sure that is updated.

P.S - Sometimes rebooting the device can also help.

Comment: I have checked all the places and there exists new name only.

Comment: @AshutoshShukla Does this happen only when you update the application, or even for fresh installs with the updated name? Can you post a screenshot of how the notification looks? Maybe that could help to investigate the problem

Comment: Also make sure you have updated your product name as well in Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name

Comment: It happens with fresh installs too. I have updated the name as well.

Comment: If it is happening with fresh install as well, then the issue must be in your project file itself. Try creating a new project, with same bundle id, and different name. and install it on your device. See if the issue still persists